# Refer to Google Glass drive via batch file

Tags: batch-file, usb, google-glass

When I connect the google glass to my PC, it opens up a new drive named "Glass". 
How can I refer to this drive in a batch file/script from any computer that I connect my glass to (independently), suppose no one would deliberately rename the drive?

I would like this bat script to copy all of the jpg and mp4 files from the Glass to some location in my PC.

Comment: I do not have access to Google Glass, but I suppose not a **drive** with volume name `Glass` is opened on connecting it to the PC, but instead a **virtual folder** with name `Glass` appears using [Media Transfer Protcol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) (MTP). If `Glass` has no drive letter, it is not a drive, it is a virtual folder. I'm not sure, but I think, it is not possible to access virtual folders using MTP from command line (batch file).

Comment: Yes, there is no letter attached to the drive appears when connecting the glass USB. So if I would like to write some automatic script that copies the files from the glass to my pc when connecting it (like many people do with a regular flash drive for auto backup for example..), there is no way to do it? alternatives for batch file maybe? Thanks!