# How to copy images from my local pc to google drive by Batch file

Tags: batch-file, automation, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a batch file (*.bat) that copy all of my images inside the local folder to some folder in Google drive (cloud). 
Please your professional help!
Thanks.

Comment: Use command [xcopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx) with appropriate parameters if the Google drive is mounted as real drive with a drive letter. But I suppose that the Google drive is not a drive, but instead a virtual folder. In this case it is not possible to synchronize Google "drive" with a local folder using a batch file, see [Refer to Google Glass drive via batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154571/). Read [Sync files and folders](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374992?hl=en) from Google Drive help and other help pages listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Robocopy should work fine.

```
robocopy "\\localhost\dir" "\\GoogleDrive\dir" /copyall /sec /mir /r:1 /w:1
```

Link to an article about it [here](http://tambnguyen.com/4248-how-i-use-google-drive-back-up-my-files/) too

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution might be to use [Google Drive CLI Client](https://github.com/glotlabs/gdrive) which has binaries available for Windows, MacOS and Linux. Once it is setup you can automate it with batch files...